K8S does not reclaim memory form spring boot + java 17 ms
K8S does not reclaim memory form spring boot + java 17 microservice. My application is developed using spring boot 3.3.2 version. While application is started it took around 350mb ram. Once load pushed on micro-service rest endpoint application start consuming 700mb ram. Stop the load after 30 mins. Wait for memory release. But application remain continue to consume 700mb.
Profiling done multiple times. fixed all large objects that are suspected as memory leaks. No more suspected objects found in heap dump. However application is continue to consumed 700mb memory.
Analyzed thread dump also. There is no increase in number of thread. it remain same as before load started.
Customized JVM options also. But does not work for us.
javaOptions:

javaOption: -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize
value: 200M
javaOption: -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize
value: 50M
javaOption: -XX:+UseContainerSupport
value: -1
javaOption: -Xms
value: 256M
javaOption: -Xmx
value: 512M
javaOption: -Xss
value: 512K
javaOption: -XX:+UseParallelGC
value: -1

Any suggestion to fix memory scale down issue on Kubernetes.

As far as I'm aware, the parallel GC doesn't return memory to the OS, so what you want is not possible with that specific garbage collector. Use a different one like G1, Shenadoah or others.

Thank for your reply. We tried with G1. But found the same result.

Refer to these troubleshooting steps mentioned in the blog by Egor Ponomarev and troubleshooting guide by Chloe which may help you to solve your problem.

Thank you for your reply. Let me analyze native memory usage in more detail.
